# Bad SOlr indexing with datastax. scaling from 1 node to 2 cassandra nodes and one search node

Tags: deployment, solr, cluster-computing, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I'm working with Datastax 3.1.4
I'm trying to go from a simple ring (with one node with Solr enable) to a little ring with 2 cassandra nodes (Solr disabled) and one search node (Solr enabled).

The cluster is well deployed according to Opscenter but when I insert data using the Solr HTTP API there is a problem...
I got no warning or error, but if values are inserted in all nodes (even the one with Solr enable) as I checked, the Solr index is wrong: According to solr only few docs are inserted 9 (whereas 20 has been inserted and are present in my cassandra table)

I'm quite sure it's a simple configuration problem, but I can't figure out what it is...

Comment: Of course, it's working with a single node cluster. is Datastax only working with solr on single noded cluster?

Comment: cassandra.yaml:http://pastebin.com/LCbKkCks
dse.yaml: http://pastebin.com/iZqiJBd7
dsetool ring output: http://pastebin.com/RxxgdYAt

Answer (score 1):

All of the Solr-enabled nodes must be in the same DC (data center), with only Solr-enabled nodes in that DC.

If you want to have non-Solr nodes, you need to put them in separate data centers than the Solr-enabled nodes.

A single DSE ring can handle multiple DC's or workloads, such as one or more Cassandra-only nodes or Cassandra-only and Hadoop analytics nodes, or Cassandra-Solr-enabled search nodes. Hadoop-enabled and Cassandra-only nodes can be mixed in the same DC, but Solr-enabled nodes cannot be mixed in a DC with Cassandra-only or Cassandra-Hadoop nodes.

You can read more about "mixed workloads" here:
http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.1/solutions/dse_search_cluster

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunaltely. My problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunaltely, it still doesn't work:
I've restrict my cluster to 2 nodes: one full cassandra on DC1 and one Solr on DC2.
Here is my cassandra-topology.properties: http://pastebin.com/RXtTQp3d

When I do nodetool status I got this:
http://pastebin.com/Y4WsQgJr

But when I insert data I still have only half which is indexed...

Comment: I also try to have only solr nodes on the same DC. But in that case, my core creation becoming huge (45s) for a quite simple schema:
http://pastebin.com/vKhmna9n

And when I try to insert data it doesn't work (or take too many time maybe cause i've stopped the process after a while)
So I really don't understand what is happening... help is really welcome

Comment: Check the output of dsetool to verify the workloads of the nodes.